# How can we use declare and use select count result in a variable inside the Create temporary table block

Tags: mysql

I'm creating temporary table and i want to assign count of select in a variable and use later code but SQL query giving me error in variable declaration

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table; 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_table AS 
(SET @test1 := select count(1) from mytable; /*Other SQL code*/)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the assignment in the list of columns.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_table
AS 
SELECT @test1 := count(1)
       FROM mytable;
```

Comment: @yogesh: Works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=f02d971dabfdfe97e7cebe585f8fc637 Must be something else you're doing wrong, something not related to the `CREATE` statement.

Comment: above code work for me too but the problem is my code is written in stored procedure, So after alias AS I have written opening bracket if I remove that then it works for me but I want opening bracket I tried many variation but still getting same error.

Comment: Hey, got solution. Actually I was using multiple select inside temp table that's why it's giving me error. I moved the declaration outside the temp table